# after insert trigger current date is not updating

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a problem in after insert trigger. when i am inserting the data in the table it should automatically update the date and it should be the current date. but when i am executing the following query it is not working properly in my table.
first i created a table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ignite`.`products`;
CREATE TABLE  `ignite`.`products`(
  `products_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `products_model` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `model_hash` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Product_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=977 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then i created this trigger:

```
use ignite;
CREATE TRIGGER created_date BEFORE INSERT ON products
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.created = NOW();
```

but when i am inserting the data in this table:

```
use ignite;
INSERT INTO products
(products_id, products_model, model_hash, Product_name)
values
(123, "456645", 457567, "awetert");
```

This is showing the following error:

```
field 'created' does not have default value. error-1364
```

Comment: your trigger is set to run BEFORE the insert, these rows you want to update do not exist yet. Also since you can set the default value of the created column to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, having a trigger do the date updating is completely unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

It's because on your `INSERT` statement does not include the `created` values. You need to include it for example with zero datetime value:

```
INSERT INTO products
(products_id, products_model, model_hash, Product_name, created)
values
(123, "456645", 457567, "awetert", "0000-00-00 00:00:00");
```